Git error message There is no -F option ("less --help" for help)
git version 2.45.0.windows.1
Windows 10 Enterprise
I have recently experienced a weird behaviour with my git installation.
Suddenly i got git not recognised as external or internal command when keying it in on the cmd command prompt.
I checked that it's actually installed under program and files, and so i added it to the system path environment variables.
It now recognises the git command but I can't access its content, branches, log, git config --global --list etc. When issuing this commands I get

there is no -F option ("less --help" for help)>

Any idea what this may be?

What precisely do you type? Does Git work if you call it with the full path? In any case, the output suggests that Git invokes less as a pager but doesn't do that correctly.

In git-bash open the 2 files /etc/gitconfig and ~/.gitconfig with notepad /etc/gitconfig and notepad ~/.gitconfig. Search for less and check if any option (like core.pager) is set to less.

I'm guessing you have an environment variable LESS with options which are not compatible with less.

no explicit mention in the config about the pager.  Nevertheless doing the command using --no-pager managed to display the expected outcome. I have done git config --global core.pager "" and now i get expected outcomes consistently. I neverthless get <error: cannot spawn --list: No such file or directory<
